# Is it illegal to take address of main() function?

Tags: c++, function, program-entry-point

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2128727/57428) *using function main() is illegal* (§3.6.1.3) and a function is *used* if its name appears in a potentially evaluated expression (§3.2).

Suppose I have this code:

```
printf( "%p", &main );
```

in which name of function `main()` appears in expression `&main`.

Will the code above be illegal?

Comment: §3.2 defines "*odr-used*", not "used". I think the meaning of "used" here is much more general - you cannot make use of `main` in any way whatsoever.

Comment: Nice question. Out of curiosity - why would you need this? Or asking your question is based on the same, I'm asking mine :)

Comment: @sftrabbit C++03 says clearly: "An object or non-overloaded
function is used if its name appears in a potentially-evaluated
expression."  C++11 doesn't say what it means by "used"; my
guess is that "odr-used" was introduced to solve some other
problem, and nobody got around to fixing the restriction on
`main`.

Comment: @JamesKanze Ah, I was looking at C++11.

Comment: also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741683/how-to-format-a-function-pointer) regarding printing a function pointer.

Comment: @sftrabbit The words restricting the use of `main` are the same in both versions.  I can't find any real definition as to what "used" means in C++11, however; unless someone can show me something else, I'll assume that the intent is the same as in C++03.

Comment: @KirilKirov: I don't know why I'd need this. I think that would be a good separate question.

Comment: It seems like an awfully dumb rule. This will effectively ban C++ from all manner of boot loaders and initialization code that needs to run before main() is called. At the same time, the C++ standard dictates that such code must exist, to handle static initialization and to run constructors of file scope objects. I suppose you are forced to write that code in C or assembler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  As you quote, the standard says that you cannot use
`main`.

Note too that the address of a function does *not* match `"%p"`.
The corresponding argument *must* have type `void*`; any other
type (except maybe `char*`) is illegal, and results in undefined
behavior.

Comment: So will I need a cast for the function address to pass it in place of `%p`?

Comment: @sharptooth Except that there is no conversion from pointer to function to `void*`.  (I think C++11 makes this an optional feature, but in earlier versions, it required a diagnostic.)

Answer (score 0):

Since `main` is not "used" (you're not evaluating it) then it should be legal according the link you supplied.

Comment: Taking the address of a function is using it.

Answer (score -3):

It's not usual to use pointer to `main()` or the address of `main()` but..

Anyway, it is allowed since, as every function (and any symbol, e.g. variable) it has its own address. And the address of main() may be needed - especially when you write code for embedded systems and you play with dynamic loading of the code or run-time inspection. Or there are a bootloader and actual running firmware.

Often `main()` is an entry point to the dynamically loaded code (e.g from FLASH to RAM) and thus it is referenced (called directly or assigned to the relevant pointer) in bootloader.

Refer to MicroC-OS/II or VxWorks - both use `main()` in this way

Comment: Unfortunately... that is completely outside the Standard. The implementation is allowed all the black magic, platform-specific code, compiler-specific code it can muster; but that does not say anything about the *portability* of the program to another platform/compiler.

Comment: I suppose that the life saver in embedded systems is that main() can be replaced with something completely custom. So, since the C++ standard is retarded, all embedded C++ implementations need to rename their main to something else. I propose that all embedded systems use `another_wg21_fiasco()` instead of `main()`, to solve this issue. Or... they could simply keep programming in C, where the standard is less retarded.