# Pointers and Arrays in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

Hey guys Im trying to get down some theoretical stuff for Pointers and Arrays. I was hoping someone could reaffirm some suspicions I had with the concept of pointers and arrays.

Suppose I had something like this

```
int ia[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
ia[2];  // =2

int* ip = &ia[0]; // pointer ip gets the address of element 0 in array ia
ip[2]; // ??
ip[2] = 42; //
```

Most of this code is theoretical obviously but im a bit unsure of the last 2 lines. First off is saying ip[2] the same as saying ip now points to the 2ndth element in the array? Is it equivalent to saying *ip = ia[2] ?

Im also confused with the last line. ip[2] = 42; so the 2ndth element of the object that the ip points to, that address gets the value 42? Or is that an array notation method of dereferencing? Im just a bit confused on whats going on.

Comment: `ip[2];` is a statement that has a value and does nothing with it. It's the same as saying `i;` `3;` or `main;`. AKA it does nothing.

Comment: oh sorry I mean...how does it have the  value 2 though? If ip originally points to the first element in the ia array then ip[2] value is 2...but logically im lost here...

Comment: It is a statement that does nothing. It's like writing `;` - also a statement that does nothing. It is equivalent to not writing the line at all. It does nothing to anything by doing it.

Comment: @Patashu, I don't think `main;` is valid (specifically due to main being special). Maybe replace it with `;` :)

Comment: @chris Have you tried it?

Comment: @Patashu, I was going from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525613/is-it-illegal-to-take-address-of-main-function), which not all compilers warn equally about. I can't say whether this constitutes as using it, though. AFAIK, these are evaluated, so that's what made me suspicious.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/381549/1383051) explains your doubt concisely.

Comment: @chris Oh, that counts as using it? I see.

Comment: as u asked ,Is it equivalent to saying *ip = ia[2] ? no not same. But *(ip+2)==ia[2]; will be true(as u have assigned address of ia to ip so ia==ip).

Comment: @Patashu, I'm not completely sure. It's not quite the same as the other question. Not really practical knowledge, but I would take comfort in knowing for sure.

Comment: culprit is not initialized k only, as its some garbage but u use it as array index ie nothing but a memory location (assume k is -564564844), then it will happily do ++k but at k[++k]=..; it will fail due to illegal memory address, & result will be seg fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following creates an array called ia and stores the numbers in curly braces in the array:

```
int ia[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
```

The following in effect, does nothing:

```
ia[2];
```

However, if I take the above statement and change as follows, it assigns the value 2 to the integer t. This is because 2 is the third element in ia, and ia[2] references the third element in ia.

```
t = ia[2];
```

If your original declaration of ia had been

```
int ia[] = {0,1,15,3,4,5};
```

then you would be assigning t to 15.

The following changes the value at index 2 in ia to 42:

```
ip[2] = 42;
```

Now, ia consists of {0,1,42,3,4,5}.

This is because ia[2] is like saying *(ia + 2). If you assign ip to ia, then ip points to the first element of ia.

Similarly, ip[2] is like saying *(ip + 2). So, changing ip[2] will change ia[2], they reference the same chunk of memory.

Answer (score 2):

`ia[n]` is a different way of writing `*(ia+n)`, therefore `int* ip = &ia[0]` is the same as `int *ip = ia`.

You are assigning `ia` to `ip`. That of course also makes `ip[n] == ia[n]` for all values of `n`.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `a[i]` it is translated to `*(a+i)` where a is the base address (basically a pointer)

Also for arrays , base address is same as address of 1st element so address of `a[0]` is same as `a` [i.e `a = &a[0]`]

So, `ip[2] = 42;` translates to `*(ip+2) = 42`
Also, * gives value at that address `ip[2] = 42` means `*(ip+2) = 42` i.e value at location `(ip+2)`

Answer (score 1):

`a[b]` is exactly the same as `*(a + b)`. ALWAYS. So `ia[2]` is equivalent to `*(ia + 2)`, and `ip[2]` is equivalent to `*(ip + 2)`.

However, it is more subtle than that because `ia` and `ip` have very different types. `ia` is of array type; whereas `ip` is of pointer type. So they are not "the same" -- they are not even the same type of thing. It's like apples and oranges.

An array expression, used within certain contexts, can be implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element. If you wrote, `int *ip = ia;`, that would be such an implicit conversion -- `ip` now points to the first element of `ia`. It is the exact same as what you wrote, `int *ip = &ia[0];`

When you write something like `*(ia + 2)`, again, in this context the array is also implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element, kind of like `*(&ia[0] + 2)`. Since we know that `ip` points to the first element of `ia`, when you use `ia` in any context where it gets converted to a pointer, it's the same as using the value of `ip`. That's why `ia[2]` and `ip[2]` work the same.