# Why cout<<main; prints 1?

Tags: c++

Why does `cout<<main;` printing `1` on my computer? I thought it would print the address of main. But when I use `printf("%x",main);` I get different output.

Edit:

I tried `std::cout` for other functions. I'm getting `1` for every case.

Comment: Why printing a function pointer produces 1 is a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064692/how-to-print-function-pointers-with-cout

Comment: Why VS2010 is giving a proper address value?

Comment: @Saksham:  Undefined behavior means *anything* can happen.  Even good things.

Comment: @JohnDibling. is undefined is related to only main or other function pointers as well?

Comment: You can take the address of other functions.

Comment: @Saksham, See the link I put. They are convertible to `bool`. Only `main` is special.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is nothing but `undefined behavior`. It is an example of a code whose behavior is unpredictable.

Comment: Citation, please.  Does the Standard forbid taking the address of `main`?

Comment: @JohnDibling, The standard forbids using `main`. 3.6.1/3 There was another question on SO about whether taking the address of it was using it, and I believe the consensus was that it was. edit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525613/is-it-illegal-to-take-address-of-main-function

Comment: Great. But in a case like this it's quite easy to explain what implementations do (just take the address of `main`, without acknowledging that `main` is special) and why it gives the output it does, because the implementation's behavior is consistent even though that's not guaranteed by the standard. I'd say adding that explanation is worthwhile (of course, the UB should still be mentioned).

Comment: @chris:  Got it, thanks.  I knew "using" main was forbidden, but I didn't know what "using" meant in this context.  Now I do, so thumbs up.

Answer (score 4):

```
void foo(){};
cout << foo << endl;
```

A function pointer will be converted to `bool`, unless use it like this:

```
cout << reinterpret_cast<void*>(foo) << endl;
```

**EDIT**: this is undefined behavior, `main` can not be used like other function pointers.

C++11(ISO/IEC 14882:2011) §3.6.1: *Main function*

> 3 The function main shall not be used within a program. The linkage (3.5) of main is implementation-defined. A program that defines main as deleted or that declares main to be inline, static, or constexpr is ill-formed. The name main is not otherwise reserved. [ Example: member functions, classes, and enumerations can be called main, as can entities in other namespaces. —end example ]

Comment: As far as I know, the standard doesn't guarantee the cast to `void *` will work (well, of course, seeing as how it's a `reinterpret_cast`, but I'm talking about `void *` and function pointer compatibility in general). It's worth keeping that in mind.