# What is printed when I write function name in C using printf() function

Tags: c, function

When I'm writing this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%p\n",main);
    printf("%d\n",main);
    return 0;
}
```

my compiler shows me this output:

```
00401318
4199192
```

I'm interested to know what actually is printed. I googled my question, but have found nothing. :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741683/how-to-format-a-function-pointer

Comment: The first one prints the address of the function, the second one would print the address of the function if `sizeof(void*)` is equal to `sizeof(int)` on your platform, but it is generally considered as undefined behavior.

Comment: @TheBigH, I didn't know the term function pointer.

Comment: Not coincidentally, 0x401318 == 4199192.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not well-defined.

You're using `%p`, which expects an argument of type `void *`, but you're actually passing it a value of type `int (*)()`, i.e. your (also badly defined) `main()` function.

You cannot portably cast a function pointer to `void *`, so your code can never be correct.

On most typicaly systems, `sizeof (void *) == sizeof main`, so you simply get the value interpreted as a `void *` which probably will simply be the address of the function.

Passing a function address to `printf()` with a format specifier of `%d` is even worse, since it's quite likely that `sizeof (int) != sizeof main` and then you get undefined behavior.

This is not good code.

Answer (score 4):

`main` is a *function pointer* of type `int(*)(void)`

1. `printf("%p\n", main);`

You are printing the address of that pointer, which, on your platform has been successfully cast to a `void*`. This will be fine if `sizeof(main) == sizeof(void*)`.

2. `printf("%d\n", main);`

This will give you *undefined behaviour* since `%d` is not a good format specifier for a pointer type.

Comment: What's about %d specifier ?

Comment: OP is printing **the value** of the pointer (which is the address of the function), not **the address** of the pointer. In addition, the second call to `printf` is guaranteed to work correctly only if `sizeof(void*)` is equal to `sizeof(int)` on OP's platform, but it is generally considered as undefined behavior. One last thing - I'm not the one who downvoted you for this answer, so please don't go around downvoting random answers of my own.

Comment: They are the same values. `%p` formats it as hex, and `%d` formats as decimal. `0x401318 == 4199192`

Comment: @robert: That's not true. For example, if OP is running on a 64-bit platform (64GB memory address space), then `%p` would be equivalent to `%lld` (or more precisely, to `%llx`).

Comment: OK. In any case, I still think you're wrong with "the address of that pointer".

Comment: Downvoted for *"`%p` should be fine though"*. Function pointers are not compatible with `void*` pointers.

Comment: Flogged this once more.