# Format specifier for pointer in PostgreSQL?

Tags: c, postgresql, pointers, indexing, postgresql-9.4

I know these threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9053658/54964) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2741683/54964) about pointers in C and printing pointer's address. 
I want to store the pointer to the postgreSQL 9.4 database with  a partial index because selection is always from a small subset of the whole data and entries are always selected in order in interals from the database.

I have a big file where I know two byte positions of the event interval: end and start. 
I know also the maximum file size:

```
## Pointer to that interval
# Start index in dec: 140
# End index in dec: 666
# File size is :  241520288
```

Table events and its eventPointer field

```
CREATE TABLE events
    (
        event_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
        measurement_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        eventPointer POINTER NOT NULL, -- TODO here for type!
        is_active BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE
    );
```

where I am not sure about the datatype and how it is efficient to store such an data interval for the partial index. 
The partial index is created by

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX dir_events 
    ON events (measurement_id)
    USING btree
    (eventPointer)
    WHERE is_active;
```

I can store these as figures but would like to have a direct pointer to the specific interval. 
I would like store pointers to the big file in partial index such that I can do fast selections. 
It may be possible that postgreSQL can do these pointers itself.

How can you store pointer in PostgreSQL's partial index?

Comment: Is it like both your `[here]`s point to the same q?

Comment: You want to store a C-pointer value in a database? Why?

Comment: @alk I am just testing what would be the optimum way to store references to my big data file. Pointers, indexes, ... I actually do not know if there is any benefit of such pointers. Possible, just stored decimal indexes but my intuition just says use pointers.

Comment: What about these types: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/rangetypes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason or benefit to storing these file indexes as pointers.

Just store the indexes using the `INTEGER` type.

Comment: I have two fields: `index_start` and `index_end` which tells where is the interval of the event. I can create two fields in the table but I am not sure if it is too much. Probably one field enough but then I should be parsing the numbers. I think I cannot store list to the field. Probably, I just should make an external table which list all event characteristics `event_id`, `start_event`, and `end_event`.

Comment: If you need both the start and the end then just put two fields in the table.  Alternatively you could store just the start and the length.