# How do I know the location of main() in memory?

Tags: c, memory

if I have a C program that begins with

```
#include
int main (void){
.
.
.
}
```

where approximately is this function? (in hex)

Comment: What?  Call something that reads the return address from the stack, or pops it and jumps to it.  Why do you need to know?

Comment: Or run it with disassembly view, with a breakpoint at main()

Comment: got this question on an exam.

Comment: This depends on platform you are working on,for example in resource constrained embedded systems you can specify the address of the main function,be more specific about the platform.

Comment: @CoolGuy Function pointers are a different class of pointers than normal variable pointers, so `%p` is not correct. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741683/how-to-format-a-function-pointer

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Thanks! I did not know that. I deleted my incorrect comment. Reading that post you linked…

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *) &main;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof &main; i++)
    {
        printf("%02x ", p[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Output on my machine:

```
55 48 89 e5 48 83 ec 20
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2741896/5399734